# Displaying data accross a seemingly randomized time sequence in a graph?

Tags: php, javascript, graph

I have a set of data in a database. In my searchings and previous attempts at such, I found jpgraph; however that isn't the best for "randomized" time-sequencing (and I don't like the layout of their gantt).

What I am looking for is a library/api/whatever for either (prefferably) PHP or (if it's awesome) javascript (prefferably jquery, but not a neccessity). Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an exemple of what you are looking for?

Comment: http://www.prodevtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/flare_timeseries_graph.png - something like that with the ability to have the data anywhere inbetween cells (on the x axis) etc.

Comment: So you are looking for a X-Y plotter that understand dates as coordinates?

Comment: Yep, that's a much better way of putting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using flot, PHP is too slow for what I need.